# Left cancellation in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $(X,+,\times)$ is a ring with additive identity $0$ and multiplicative identity $1$. Let $x,y \in X$.

> If $xy + yx = 1$ and $xxx = x$, then $xx = 1$.

How to prove this proposition? We can observe that
$$ (xy + xx)^2 = xyxy + xyxx + xxxy + xxxx = xyxy+xyxx+xy+xx = xy(xy+xx+1) + xx
$$
I am not sure how would I proceed from here.

Comment: Isn't this ring kind of trivial? Since from $xy + yx = 1$, when one substitutes $ x =y = 1$ you get $1+1 = 1$, i.e. $1 = 0$ and hence $ x = 1x = 0x = 0$?

Comment: @pepa.dvorak $x,y$ are not arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $xxy =  x(xy +  yx - yx)  = x - xyx = x - (xy +yx - yx)x = x -x + yxx = yxx$.

We already know  that $xxxy = xy$. From the above, $xxyx = yxxx = yx$.

Hence, $xx = xx(xy+yx) = xxxy + xxyx = xy + yx = 1$.

Comment: Thanks. What is a general strategy for solving these kinds of problems?

Comment: These kinds of problems usually involve plenty of algebraic play. I am not very good at it, unfortunately. I would think, like ordinary problem solving, that this comes with practice. I should tell you that I spent one and a half hours figuring out this one! (So, my strategy was literally brute force).